# magento import products not showing up on frontend version 2,1.1

Tags: indexing, import, magento2, reindex

I have installed Magento 2 on our domain but and I'm facing some error,

I have imports products with CSV file and all the products import successfully and showing up in back-end in the admin panel,but products cannot be showing up in front-end.

I also clear Magento cache.But in index management panel I cannot reindex the data and getting the error that reindexing is required.I can't find any solution please help,and tell me our to reindex data from panel with command line

Comment: have you run indexer:reindex command?

Comment: yes i have run this command on my local machine but i don't know how to run this command on cpanel can you please explain

Comment: Any solution about that ?